# Swift 3 - declaring NSMutableArray data type with custom objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3, nsmutablearray, declaration

I'm having trouble declaring a NSMutableArray in Swift 3 because using legacy objective C code bridges the swift `Array` data type to `NSArray`.  Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
var myMutableArray: NSMutableArray = [myObjectCustomClass]
```

But I'm getting a compiling error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[myObjectCustomClass].Type' (aka
>   'Array.Type' to specified type 'NSMutableArray'

I've tried a few other ways as well such as:

```
var myMutableArray = NSMutableArray<myObjectCustomClass>
var myMutableArray:[myObjectCustomClass] = NSMutableArray<myObjectCustomClass>
```

but no luck.  Any ideas?

Comment: `var myMutableArray = NSMutableArray()`?

Comment: Yes, that declares a NSMutableArray; however, the items in the NSMutableArray should be of type `myObjectCustomClass`.  How would I add that?

Comment: You can't, `NSMutableArray` lets you add objects of any type to it.  That's why you use swift arrays.

Comment: Ah... ok, Dan.  I see.  Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2):

You have not initialised your myObjectCustomClass while declaring as a NSMutableArray that's why its showing the error. You can initialise the array at the time of declaring or can later add elements to the array as its declared var

try initialising when you declare

```
var myMutableArray: NSMutableArray = [myObjectCustomClass()] 
or 
var myMutableArray: [myObjectCustomClass] = [myObjectCustomClass()] //swift 3 way
```

or alternatively declare as a CustomClass Array variable and later add objects

```
 var myMutableArray: [myObjectCustomClass] = []
 let myObjectCustomClass = myObjectCustomClass()
 myMutableArray.append(myObjectCustomClass)
```